# Resolving ambiguity with derived class nested type in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, inner-classes

This is the code:

```swift
class CommonField {
    init(name: String) {}
}
class Base {
    class Field: CommonField {}
}
class Derived: Base {
    class Field: CommonField {}
}

let a = CommonField(name: "field") // works fine
let b = Base.Field(name: "base.field") // works fine
let c = Derived.Field(name: "derived.field") // error!
```

This is the error:

```
error: ambiguous use of 'init(name:)'
let c = Derived.Field(name: "derived.field")
    ^
note: found this candidate
class Field: CommonField {}
^
note: found this candidate
class Field: CommonField {}
^
```

I'm using following version of swift compiler:

```
Apple Swift version 4.2.1 (swiftlang-1000.11.42 clang-1000.11.45.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
```

Comment: What is the purpose of defining `class Field` in the subclass again? Just remove it!

Comment: Arguably the compiler should reject the second nested definition of `Field` with a redeclaration error

Comment: Filed a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10113

Comment: Is there any case at all where redeclaration of nested class in derived class can be useful?

Comment: You should be aware that in Swift there are no real nested types. Declaring a new type inside another type only affects the namespace of the inner type, there will be no type relation between the two types.